# Saving Record To Database Takes Too Long

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to save a record to Oracle DB in Spring Boot project. I am taking an input from rest services, running a logic and saving result into DB. While I search my logs, I saw that some of records are been saved in 10 to 20 ms but some of them saved in thousand milliseconds. I suspect of data source pooling but i am not sure. Is there any mistake in here?

## JPA Configuration

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.ykb.frd.fraudbase.repository.hibernate.fraud",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "fraudEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "fraudTransactionManager")
public class FraudConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fraudEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(fraudDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.ykb.frd.fraudbase.entity.fraud");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource fraudDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                .create(this.dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(env.getProperty("driver-class-name"))
                .url(env.getProperty("fraud.url"))
                .username(env.getProperty("fraud.username"))
                .password(env.getProperty("fraud.password"));
        return factory.build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager fraudTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(fraudEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

## Repository

```
@Repository
public interface FraudRequestTransactionsRepository extends CrudRepository<FraudRequestTransactionsEntity, Long> {
}
```

## Saving To Database

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BaseService service = baseServices.length > 0 ? baseServices[0] : null;
        FraudRequestTransactionsEntity fraudRequestTransactionsEntity = new FraudRequestTransactionsEntity();
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setLuc(0);
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setTransactionId(fraudActionsRestRequest.getTransactionId());
        if (fraudActionsRestRequest.getSenderClientNo() != null)
            fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setClientNo(Integer.parseInt(fraudActionsRestRequest.getSenderClientNo()));
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setTransactionId(fraudActionsRestRequest.getTransactionId());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setUserId(fraudActionsRestRequest.getUserId());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setChannelName(fraudActionsRestRequest.getChannel());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setProcessCode(fraudActionsRestRequest.getProcessCode());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setProcessName(fraudActionsRestRequest.getProcessName());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setRequest(requestMessage);
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setTransactionStatus("FINISHED");
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setSessionId(fraudActionsRestRequest.getSessionId());
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setTransactionDate(date.getTime());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setTransactionMillisecond(date.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setAmount(fraudActionsRestRequest.getTlAmount());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setCurrency(fraudActionsRestRequest.getSenderCurrencyCode());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setDeviceId(fraudActionsRestRequest.getDeviceId());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setReceiverAccountNo(fraudActionsRestRequest.getReceiverAccountNo());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setTransactionType(fraudActionsRestRequest.getFraudTransactionsMapEntity().getTransactionType());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setSenderCardNo(fraudActionsRestRequest.getSenderCreditCardNumber());
        fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setTransactionSequenceNo(Long.toString(fraudActionsRestRequest.getTransactionSequenceNo()));
        //TODO zeynep & berkin : bu alanları almamız gereken yerlere bakılacak
        /*fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setSubScriberNo(fraudActionsRestRequest.get);
        if(fraudActionsRestRequest.getFraudTransactionsMapEntity().getTransactionType().equalsIgnoreCase(FalconUtil.RBTRAN)){
            fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setReceiverClientNo(((RbtranServiceInputModel)service).);
            fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setReceiverCardNo(((RbtranServiceInputModel)service).);
            fraudRequestTransactionsEntity.setReceiverPhoneNo(((RbtranServiceInputModel)service).);
        }*/

        fraudRequestTransactionsRepository.save(fraudRequestTransactionsEntity);
        log.info("[{}] REQ DB Yazma Süresi {}", fraudActionsRestRequest.getTransactionId(), System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

## Logs

```
> 2019-02-01 09:31:03,671 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [1550097604112] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 33
> 2019-02-01 09:32:04,338 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-8] [1548428179551] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 23
> 2019-02-01 09:32:38,260 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-8] [1549819439559] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 39
> 2019-02-01 09:33:41,725 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [1548871854756] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 654
> 2019-02-01 09:34:04,093 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-9] [1551123829603] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 7841
> 2019-02-01 09:34:04,104 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-4] [1548256231753] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 18835
> 2019-02-01 09:34:50,452 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [1550169566966] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 100
> 2019-02-01 09:35:52,729 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-8] [1548634610667] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 17
> 2019-02-01 09:36:48,676 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-9] [1548513532722] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 26
> 2019-02-01 09:37:29,116 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-10] [1547445362906] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 17
> 2019-02-01 09:39:09,091 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-4] [1548339052481] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 19
> 2019-02-01 09:39:53,977 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [1547701783551] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 51
> 2019-02-01 09:40:31,429 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [1550619321669] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 20
> 2019-02-01 09:41:12,516 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [1549734992552] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 31
> 2019-02-01 09:42:42,585 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [1550174884815] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 38
> 2019-02-01 09:44:10,962 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [1547618724242] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 40
> 2019-02-01 09:47:26,009 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-5] [1548172574161] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 53
> 2019-02-01 09:47:57,171 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [1548842916526] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 33
> 2019-02-01 09:47:58,080 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-5] [1547521859756] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 27
> 2019-02-01 09:49:13,696 INFO com.ykb.frd.fraudcommon.CommonApplication [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [1550270365545] REQ DB Yazma Süresi 974
```

Thanks.

Comment: It probably won't make a lot of difference, but I think I'd move `long start = System.currentTimeMillis();` so that it is immediately before `fraudRequestTransactionsRepository.save(fraudRequestTransactionsEntity)`. There's a lot happening between starting and stopping the timer. You are assuming the time is spent in the DB interaction, but you haven't proved that yet.

Comment: There is no logic inside of setter functions. I am sure that there is a problem in saving

Comment: What about login in the getters on the `fraudActionsRestRequest` object?

Comment: Same as setters. Nothing important